# Tensorflow Graphics Math

Tags: python, tensorflow

*Hello everybody. I'm asking for help because I can't find the math attribute.

Some advice?

I would like to use this optimizer :

tfg.math.optimizer.levenberg_marquardt*

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xp64q.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this optimizer `tfg.math.optimizer.levenberg_marquardt.minimize` by this way.

Sample code:

```
!pip install --upgrade tensorflow-graphics
import tensorflow_graphics as tfg
from tensorflow_graphics.math.optimizer.levenberg_marquardt import minimize

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = tf.constant(np.random.random_sample(size=(1,2)), dtype=tf.float32)
y = tf.constant(np.random.random_sample(size=(3,1)), dtype=tf.float32)

def f1(x, y):
  return x + y

def f2(x, y):
  return x * y

def callback(iteration, objective_value, variables):
  def print_output(iteration, objective_value, *variables):
    print("Iteration:", iteration, "Objective Value:", objective_value)
    for variable in variables:
      print(variable)
  inp = [iteration, objective_value] + variables
  return tf.py_function(print_output, inp, [])

#Specified Optimizer: tfg.math.optimizer.levenberg_marquardt.minimize
minimize_op = minimize(residuals=(f1, f2),
                       variables=(x, y),
                       max_iterations=10,
                       callback=callback)

if not tf.executing_eagerly():
  with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(minimize_op)
```

Output:

```
Iteration: tf.Tensor(1, shape=(), dtype=int32) Objective Value: tf.Tensor(7.2594, shape=(), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([[0.8147531  0.88018274]], shape=(1, 2), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[[0.6898391]
 [0.6754096]
 [0.4726268]], shape=(3, 1), dtype=float32)
Iteration: tf.Tensor(2, shape=(), dtype=int32) Objective Value: tf.Tensor(7.2594, shape=(), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([[0.8147531  0.88018274]], shape=(1, 2), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[[0.6898391]
 [0.6754096]
 [0.4726268]], shape=(3, 1), dtype=float32)
Iteration: tf.Tensor(3, shape=(), dtype=int32) Objective Value: tf.Tensor(7.2594, shape=(), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([[0.8147531  0.88018274]], shape=(1, 2), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[[0.6898391]
 [0.6754096]
 [0.4726268]], shape=(3, 1), dtype=float32)
Iteration: tf.Tensor(4, shape=(), dtype=int32) Objective Value: tf.Tensor(7.2594, shape=(), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([[0.8147531  0.88018274]], shape=(1, 2), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[[0.6898391]
 [0.6754096]
 [0.4726268]], shape=(3, 1), dtype=float32)
WARNING:tensorflow:5 out of the last 5 calls to <function pfor.<locals>.f at 0x7f421841d830> triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive and the excessive number of tracings could be due to (1) creating @tf.function repeatedly in a loop, (2) passing tensors with different shapes, (3) passing Python objects instead of tensors. For (1), please define your @tf.function outside of the loop. For (2), @tf.function has experimental_relax_shapes=True option that relaxes argument shapes that can avoid unnecessary retracing. For (3), please refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#controlling_retracing and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function for  more details.
Iteration: tf.Tensor(5, shape=(), dtype=int32) Objective Value: tf.Tensor(7.2594, shape=(), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([[0.8147531  0.88018274]], shape=(1, 2), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[[0.6898391]
 [0.6754096]
 [0.4726268]], shape=(3, 1), dtype=float32)
WARNING:tensorflow:6 out of the last 6 calls to <function pfor.<locals>.f at 0x7f421d31e7a0> triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive and the excessive number of tracings could be due to (1) creating @tf.function repeatedly in a loop, (2) passing tensors with different shapes, (3) passing Python objects instead of tensors. For (1), please define your @tf.function outside of the loop. For (2), @tf.function has experimental_relax_shapes=True option that relaxes argument shapes that can avoid unnecessary retracing. For (3), please refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#controlling_retracing and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function for  more details.
Iteration: tf.Tensor(6, shape=(), dtype=int32) Objective Value: tf.Tensor(7.2594, shape=(), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([[0.8147531  0.88018274]], shape=(1, 2), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[[0.6898391]
 [0.6754096]
 [0.4726268]], shape=(3, 1), dtype=float32)
Iteration: tf.Tensor(7, shape=(), dtype=int32) Objective Value: tf.Tensor(7.2594, shape=(), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([[0.8147531  0.88018274]], shape=(1, 2), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[[0.6898391]
 [0.6754096]
 [0.4726268]], shape=(3, 1), dtype=float32)
Iteration: tf.Tensor(8, shape=(), dtype=int32) Objective Value: tf.Tensor(7.2594, shape=(), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([[0.8147531  0.88018274]], shape=(1, 2), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[[0.6898391]
 [0.6754096]
 [0.4726268]], shape=(3, 1), dtype=float32)
Iteration: tf.Tensor(9, shape=(), dtype=int32) Objective Value: tf.Tensor(7.2594, shape=(), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([[0.8147531  0.88018274]], shape=(1, 2), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[[0.6898391]
 [0.6754096]
 [0.4726268]], shape=(3, 1), dtype=float32)
Iteration: tf.Tensor(10, shape=(), dtype=int32) Objective Value: tf.Tensor(7.2594, shape=(), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([[0.8147531  0.88018274]], shape=(1, 2), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[[0.6898391]
 [0.6754096]
 [0.4726268]], shape=(3, 1), dtype=float32)
```

Also, refer this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/graphics/api_docs/python/tfg/math/optimizer/levenberg_marquardt/minimize) for more information.